# Text inside TextView moves when using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that I want to add some drawable inside it using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds , the problem is that when I do so the text moves and not aligned to a TextView near it that doesn't have the drawable.

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView();
TextView tv2 = new TextView();

Drawable icon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.arrow_right_down,null);
                tv1.setPadding(ARROW_PADDING,0,0,0);
                tv1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        icon, null, null, null);

tv1.setText("A");
tv2.setText("A");
```

problem - A's are not aligned. ofcourse if I remove the drawable the text is aligned. 
The TextViews are located on near the other so it really easy to see it.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? That is, what are you trying to accomplish now that you know what does happen?

Comment: @MikeM. I just want that the texts to be alligned :)

Comment: Well, you could add a transparent `Drawable` of the same size to the other one. Or you could get the width of `icon`, and add that to the left padding of the other one. Or you could left-offset the other `TextView` by that width. Etc. I'd probably go with the second one.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks Mike. The problem is that this is a grid , so it is realy important that all texts will be aligned and the drawable can appear on all 4 positions. Isn't there a way of adding the drawable and making the text to not "move" ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a padding and there is an image. 
If you calculate them and then substract them to the padding - it will work.

just add :

```
int padding = IMG_SIZE+ARROW_PADDING;
this.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-padding );
```